# Rails combine joins, where, group and limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got following data structure that needs a good query:

user_event.rb:

```
belongs_to :event
```

event.rb

```
has_many :user_events
```

And the table content looks like this:

user_events:

| id | user_id | event_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 2022-01-02 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | 2022-01-03 |

events:

| id | type | metdata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sign_up | ... |
| 2 | update_profile | ... |
| 3 | sign_up | ... |
| 4 | delete_account | ... |
| 5 | update_profile | ... |

Now I need a query that returns only the most recent events of each user.

So the result would be this:

| user_events.user_id | events.type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sign_up |
| 2 | delete_account |
| 3 | update_profile |

How can I do that?

Comment: It depends on what DB you're using and what level of performance your need vs complexity. https://www.salsify.com/blog/engineering/most-recent-by-group-in-rails

Comment: It's PostgreSQL and it should obviously have good performance. I'll check your link, thanks!